# Google reCaptcha conflicts with spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, recaptcha

My site using `spl_autoload_register` to call any classes located in folder `class\` . It works great  but when I want to require Google reCaptcha library in the page. `spl_autoload_register` considers `recaptcha\recaptcha` as a class and automatically calls it like a class file in from class folder. How can I fix this? Thank you.

**core\core.php**

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $path = "class/" . $class . ".php";
    require_once($path);
});
```

**post.php**

```
require_once ("core/core.php");
require('exLib/captcha/autoload.php');
$secret = CONFIG::getCaptchaKey("secretKey");
$reCaptcha = new \recaptcha\recaptcha($secret);
$gReCaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$remoteIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$resp = $reCaptcha->verify($gReCaptchaResponse, $remoteIP);
if (!$resp->issuccess()) {
    echo "invalid";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "valid";
}
```

**errors**

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'class/recaptcha\recaptcha.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php56/pear') in /home/user/public_html/home/core/core.php on line 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check wether the file exists or not.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
$path = "class/" . $class . ".php";
if(file_exists($path))
    require_once($path);
});
```

Or you use `include();` because it emits a warning.

Comment: This answer doesn't work. It's not a warning, it's an error. The if condition always return false and the function doesn't load the file from library because `recaptcha\recaptcha` is not a class in `class` folder.

Comment: The function should not load it. You create it via a namespace. So you need to require the class for recaptcha seperate or add a else if etc. to the spl_autoload. But you did not post any information about the second library or where the file should be located...

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help :)